# Sumatra PDF : unknown source on some documents (Tex Live 2019, Sublime Text 3)

Tags: sublime-text, sumatrapdf, texlive-2019

Up until a few days ago, I had TexLive 2018. Everything was working. Then, I installed TexLive 2019 (at last). I am working with Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10.

Everything is compiling, there is no problem there. Sumatra opens after the compilation, always, but for some documents it doesn't scroll to the place where the cursor is in the .tex file. When it does not scroll, I receive a tiny message on top of the pdf file that stays for a few seconds:

> Unknown source file (C:\yadayadayada\document.tex)

I observed that if I revert back to Tex Live 2018, the problem persists but if I delete all the .aux, .out, ... beforehand, and then compile with Tex Live 2018, there is no problem, there is no message of an unknown source file. When I come back to Tex Live 2019, the problem reappears.

The inverse search is working in all cases.

Any hint about what is happening is welcome, I'd really like to understand the problem (even if no solution exists at the moment). Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have spaces in the folder name?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why not? The *standard* Windows directory structure has spaces in its folder names - e.g. "Program Files" and "My Documents". Sure, Linux gets sniffy about it, but Windows doesn't.

Comment: @alephzero windows gets "sniffy" about spaces in various places too, I would accept a bet that e.g. synctex likes them.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ah no, sorry. I just put yada yada yada because the path is long. There are only letters and underscores.